# JFREECHART line chart : Want X axis to be collection of date ranges

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am new to JFreeChart. My requirement is to display the X axis (time-axis) as following (time ranges will be configurable as per user input) for a line chart with suppose 3 variables:

3rdAug-8thAug..10thAug-15thAug..  [ and so on ]

Currently my graph's X axis is like this :

1..2..3..4..5 ..

[Unable to attach screenshots]

My demo code is as follows :

```
private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {

    // create the chart...
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
        "Line Chart Demo ",      // chart title
        "X",                      // x axis label
        "Y",                      // y axis label
        dataset,                  // data
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
        true,                     // include legend
        true,                     // tooltips
        false                     // urls
    );

    //  OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION OF THE CHART...
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);



    // get a reference to the plot for further customisation...
    final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
    plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
    plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

    final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, true);  //for line visibility
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
    plot.setRenderer(renderer);
    // change the auto tick unit selection to integer units only...
    final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
   // final Axis range = plot.get

    rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
    // OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION COMPLETED.

    return chart;

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?
How do I get only the required values shown on the X axis?

Answer (score 0):

XYPlot differ between domain axes and range axes. In your case the X axis is the domain axis whereas the Y axis is the range axis.

```
Valuexis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
```

You can also set a different domain axis:

```
ValueAxis dAxis = new ...
plot.setDomainAxis(dAxis);
```

Comment: Does that answer your question? In such a case please mark your question as resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JFreeChart's [TimeLine](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Timeline.html) interface to limit the shown dates on the [DateAxis](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html) (which is actually the domain-axis in your case, as already pointed out by @Uli). For your requirement the default implementation [SegmentedTimeline](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/SegmentedTimeline.html) should fulfill your requirements. Just configure it and pass it on to your axis:

```
SegmentedTimeline timeline = new SegmentedTimeline(
    86400000l,  // segment size = one day in ms (24*3600*1000)
    5,          // include 5 segments (days)
    2);         // exclude 2 segments (days)
DateAxis axis = new DateAxis();
axis.setTimeline(timeline);
```

And don't forget to configure the plot to use the new `DateAxis`, as `XYPlot` uses `NumberAxis` by default:

```
plot.setDomainAxis(axis);
```

hth,
- martin